# What does 'serializer.initial_data' mean?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How can I use 'serializer.initial_data' in Django Rest-API. 
What is the difference between using request.data and serializer.initial_data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When passing data to a serializer instance, **the unmodified data** will be made available as **`.initial_data`**. If the **`data`** keyword argument is not passed then the `.initial_data` attribute will not exist.

```
serializer = MyFooSerializer(data={'foo':'bar'})
print(serializer.initial_data) # this will print {'foo':'bar'}
```

The [**`request.data`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data) returns the parsed content of the **request body**.

Answer (score 3):

Requests.data contains the data that comes in from the frontend. Arguably, you should leave `requests.data` alone and use a serializer to convert said data into more complex types. The use cases for serializers are pretty vast ranging, but the most common is translation of data into database model instances.